# Navbar image between title and buttons

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Is there a way to put a image or some text next to the buttons on the left and right side, but not clickable?
I want to provide some user info (just a number) that's always visible, but it's not an action, so no button.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a custom component for the navBar, using:

> navBarCustomView: 'example.CustomTopBar' //registered component name

you can have a look to the style format for the navBar in the [docs](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/blob/master/docs/styling-the-navigator.md#style-object-format)